# Nativescript Vue v-if memory leak

Tags: vue.js, memory, memory-leaks, nativescript, nativescript-vue

### Issue

https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/492

#### brief synopsis

Using a custom tab-routing strategy in Nativescript-Vue I found that my application was leaking memory. The routing strategy relies on one overarching component that will toggle active components via a v-if statement. When the user navigates to a new page, the v-if statement will hide(and destroy) the old page and show(and mount) the new page. In theory the old page should be destroyed and the memory collected by the garbage collector; however, in practice the memory piles up and never seems to be released from the application, even when calling the garbage collector manually.

#### testing and reproduction

This issue was tested and found on a real ios device (emulator seems to have no memory issues but I have read that it's not like a real device). The github issue provided above can provide some further detail, and the repository linked below demonstrates a minimal reproduction to cause a memory leak.

A reproduction of this error can be found at https://github.com/geodav-tech/nativescript-vue-memory-leak.

After building the project, run it through xcode, look at the memory profile, and navigate back and forth from the states list to the example list that gets generated on mounted. screenshots also provided within readme

I expect the memory of the hidden components to be cleaned up after they are destroyed and currently even if you leave the app open for several minutes the garbage collector does not reduce the load.

#### question (edit)

Does anyone have any reasoning behind the memory being held by the application? Is there a better way to accomplish a routing strategy similar to this that wouldn't cause a memory leak or is something about the flow of the program a bad strategy?

Comment: It may be more appropriate to post this in the form of a question regarding the original issue, and then submit your current post's content as an answer and accept it. This will avoid leaving this "question" open, will keep it within the ordinary format of SO questions, and will likely make it easier for others to find this information in the future.

Comment: Did you try to use `hide()` or `destroy()` methods to avoid it? More examples can be found here: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: I'm not sure I follow since the destroy method listed in that example is from an external library. There should be nothing to destroy in the reproduction I provided. It is an array of random id's and incremental names. Setting this array to null or an empty array before it is destroyed also has no effect on memory conservation. I created the reproduction repository using only vanilla javascript and nativescript-vue. there is no external `destroy()` to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone facing memory leak issues similar to this, the answer lies in updating.
The projects facing this issue were compiled against:
nativescript ios runtime: 5.0.0
nativescript android runtime: 5.0.0
tns-core-modules: 5.0.2
nativescript-vue: 2.0.0

Updating to the following fixed the issue.
nativescript ios runtime: 5.4.0
nativescript android runtime: 5.4.0
tns-core-modules: 5.4.0
nativescript-vue: 2.2.2

Now the exact same structure is freed up once navigated away from.